# Scientific notation in plot title

Tags: plotting, output-formatting

I have problem with displaying variables in scientific notation in plot title.  Below is my code sample,

```
ClearAll;
f1[a_,b_,c_]:=a*x^2+b*x^3+c;
f2[a_,b_,c_]:=a*x+b*x^2+(2-x)*c;
x=Range[0,10,0.01];
a1=1.0;b1=2.0;c1=0.000000001;
f3=f2[a1,b1,c1]+f1[a1,1,c1];
plot1=ListPlot[f3,PlotLabel->Style[" a="<>ToString[a1]<>"   b="<>ToString[b1]<>" c="<>ToString[c1]]]
```

It works on simple decimal numbers.  However, longer decimals do not display properly.  How to fix that?

Comment: With that many data points `ListLinePlot` produces a clearer, sharper plot. However, `ListPlot` has an advantage if you you want to include `Tooltip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason to use [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString), and I especially avoid using `ToString[expr, TraditionalForm]` if at all possible. Instead, I would do:

```
ListPlot[
    f3,
    PlotLabel->Row[{a==a1, b==b1, c==c1},"    "]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Until now I also used often `ToString` to produce labels in plots, What is the disadvantage of it?

Comment: @mrz Anything you can do with ToString you should be able to do with Row. ToString has issues. For instance `ToString[1.1*^-8]` or `ToString[Subscript[x,1]]`. And I don't like StandardForm/TraditionalForm because I don't like linear syntax (e.g., "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\)]\)"). Finally, InputForm typically isn't useful (e.g., ToString[Subscript[x, 1], InputForm]). I much prefer creating an expression instead of a string as a label.

Answer (score 1):

```
PlotLabel -> 
 Style[" a=" <> ToString[a1, TraditionalForm] <> "   b=" <> 
   ToString[b1, TraditionalForm] <> " c=" <> 
   ToString[c1, TraditionalForm]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want to write all decimals or not. I am assuming the first case as the statement says "It works on simple decimal numbers". Thus, be advised you can increase the threshold for representing number in the scientific form by using `ScientifcNotationThreshold` in `NumberForm` along the numerator of digits and decimals, and along the suggestion of @BobHanlon for a clearer plot:

```
ClearAll;
f1[a_, b_, c_] := a*x^2 + b*x^3 + c;
f2[a_, b_, c_] := a*x + b*x^2 + (2 - x)*c;
x = Range[0, 10, 0.01];
a1 = 1.0000000000034; b1 = 2.0; c1 = 0.000000001;
f3 = f2[a1, b1, c1] + f1[a1, 1, c1];
plot1 = ListLinePlot[f3, 
        PlotLabel -> 
       Row[Style[#, 12, Black, Bold, SingleLetterItalics -> False] & /@
       {a ==NumberForm[a1, {18, 17}, ScientificNotationThreshold -> {-25, 25}],
       b == b1, 
       c == NumberForm[c1, {10, 9}, ScientificNotationThreshold -> {-15, 15}]
       }, Invisible["spc"]
       ]
]
```

[image]

[image]

### Edit

The suggestions by Carl have been added (avoid use of `ToString` whenever posible). It is also included a second plot when the label is dangerously long by using `Column` with option `Aligment-> Left`, instead of `Row`.

Comment: If you change `b` to `2*^-17` the output is horrendous. This is one of the reasons I strongly discourage the use of single-argument `ToString`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. However, guessing it, just use `NumberForm` as for `a1` and `c1`...

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant change `a1 = 1.0000000000034` to `a1=2.0*^-17`.

Comment: @CarlWoll change to `ToString@NumberForm[a1, {18, 17}, 
  ScientificNotationThreshold -> {-25, 25}]` ;))

Comment: Oh @CarlWoll, if row makes a very long label, then change `Row` to `Column`

Comment: If you used my approach, you wouldn't have to worry about the bad linebreaking that ToString does.

Comment: @CarlWoll Your approach does not allow to apply `Style` on variables (`a`, `b`...) doesn't it? Always will be in `Italic`, and maybe one will not want them to be so, or am I missing something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69869/discussion-between-carl-woll-and-jose-antonio-diaz-navas).